Are there other symbols in use that were created by Amper
I have been pronouncing & as 'Ampersand' , but I realise now that it is supposed to be 'Amper's And'.
Are there other symbols that Mr Amper created that are in common use?

What's the source of this misinformation? I think you're badly mistaken.

You can get all amped up about this sort of thing if you’re not careful.

The origin of the ampersand and its name have already been covered at Where did the character & come from and why....

You're joking, right? Always include references and cite sources in your questions, that way you'll share your research and avoid future embarrassments.

The exclamation mark was named after a guy called Exclamation Mark who used to shout a lot.

Stuart's comment is another joke, Rohit.

@Mari-LouA You mean Mister Tiro wasn't really Mister Amper? :)

I don't know where you got that origin story from, but it is wrong.
It is derived from the Latin word Et, meaning 'and', written in old-fashioned script.
It was frequently used with c to make &c, to abbreviate et cetera.
When used on its own, it was called 'and per se'  (and by itself)  which became "ampersand".
See wiki for details.

Please post details rather than merely providing a link (which may decay over time).. Though in this case, a previous question about the origin of the ampersand exists, so further answers should be added there (if containing any different material).

I thought I had provided details.  What else do you think I should have added?

If you look at the format of Daniel's answer in the duplicate mentioned, you'll see a block quote (linked and attributed). Providing such quotes (rather than just pointing to them and perhaps briefly summarising) is considered standard in answers on ELU. // But as said, this question has been dealt with before. Though it (the question here)  is now closed because of lack of basic research, the duplicate issue really means that no answers should be given here.
